# This question is regarding A C program to replace the second the subsequent occurences of the digit with 0,-1,-2... so on so if 1,1,1 -> 1,0,-1

Tags: arrays, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[]={1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1};
    int count=1;
    int size=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    for(int k=0;k<=size;k++){
           for(int i=0;i<=size;i++){
        count = 1;
        for(int j=i+1;j<=size;j++){
        if(a[j]==a[i]){
           count--; 
            a[j]=count
      }
} }}
```

I tried like just two loops,and using a count variable to decrease the value to get the output like 1,2,0,0,-1,-1 for the array 1,2,1,2,1,2 as 1 and 2 repeating 3 three times but Im getting error with Second digit ie '2' im getting 2,0,0,0... like 1 2 0 0 -1 0 -2 0 -3.

Comment: It shoudl be `k<size`, `j<size` and `i<size` because you start counting at 0.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Maybe we have a language problem; your question is very unclear. You want your code to do *what?* Take a sequence nj and turn it into nj-j, or what?

Comment: @Beta hi sir i just want to replace the second and subsequent numbers with 0,-1,-2,-3

Comment: so if 2 repeats 3 three times ,leaving its first occurenes 2,0,-1 it should be replaced

Comment: So Im giving a input like 1,2,1,2,1,2 the output should be 1,2,0,0,-1,-1 but im getting error with 2 As im getting output as 1,2,0,0,-1,0 ,im tried with extending the array size im only

Answer (score 0):

You have too many loops, and invoke [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) by accessing the element one-past the end of the array.

If the array is being changed in place, you must account for the fact that values less than `1` will hold special meaning as marked duplicates. In this case all values in the array must be greater than zero beforehand.

Otherwise, elements already marked as duplicates will be used as candidates to check for more duplicates.

For example, with the data:

```
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
|  |
```

After the first two elements are checked the array will be

```
1, 2, 0, 0, -1, -1
      |
```

When the third element is checked, the fourth element will be changed to a zero (although its already a zero).

When the fifth element is checked

```
1, 2, 0, 0, -1, -1
             |
```

the sixth element will be changed to a zero, resulting in:

```
1, 2, 0, 0, -1, 0
```

So values less than `1` must be excluded from the duplicate sweep, or a copy of the array must be used.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(int *data, size_t length)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%2d ", data[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    int list[] = { 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1 };
    size_t length = sizeof list / sizeof *list;

    print_array(list, length);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (list[i] > 0) {
            int rep = 0;

            for (size_t j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
                if (list[j] == list[i]) {
                    list[j] = rep--;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    print_array(list, length);
}
```

```
 1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1 
 1  2  0  0 -1 -1 -2 -2 -3
```